# Problemas caché proyecto Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, cache, manifest

Mis siguientes dos problemas creo que estan relacionados a la memoria caché que se genera en el proyecto gradle
Problema 1: 
Cuando comencé a crear mi aplicación tenía pensado usar la cámara por lo cuál declare el permiso en el archivo Manifest.xml pero despues de un tiempo decidí revocarlo borrándolo del Manifest.xml porque ya no lo iba a utilizar. EL problema es que al crear el APK y ejecutarlo en el dispositivo sigue apareciendo en permisos de la aplicación.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.unam.centroculturalacatln">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".SplashScreen" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Inicio" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity android:name=".PreviaLogin" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity android:name=".DecripcionCompleta" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity android:name=".ImagenTamanoCompleto" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity android:name=".GeneradorCortesia" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity android:name=".iniciar_sesion" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity android:name=".Evento" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity android:name=".Registro" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>


        <service android:name=".FirebaseCloudMessaging">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Problema 2:
Tenía una clase para generar notificaciones usando Firebase Cloud Messaging me funcionaba bien pero quise cambiar las propiedades por defecto como ícono, sonido y vibración pero cuando lo hacía nunca se veían reflejados los cambios. Generé un nuevo método al cual llamar para crear la notificación pero al parecer siempre llamaba al otro método con configuracion de la notificacion por defecto aunque lo borrara. Opté por borrar la clase completa y crear otra que solo mostrara un Log en consola y eliminar la clase anterior pero aún sin el código para crear la notificación se sigue mostrando la notificación con los 
Mi código de esta nueva clase se limita a esto:

```
package com.unam.centroculturalacatln;

import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

import static androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Constraints.TAG;

public class FirebaseCloudMessaging extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onNewToken(@NonNull String token) {

        super.onNewToken(token);
        Log.i(TAG,"Nuevo token: "+token);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        Log.i(TAG,"Mensaje de: "+remoteMessage.getFrom());

        if(remoteMessage.getNotification()!=null){
            createNotification();
        }

    }

    public void createNotification(){
        Log.i(TAG,"Method: createNotification()");
    }
}
```

Pero en vez de crear el simple Log genera una notificación con los valores por defecto aunque no existe ningun gódigo para crear dicha notificación

Supongo que se debe a que el permiso se quedó almacenado en caché del proyecto gradle
Ya intenté con:

- La opcion del IDE File->Invalidate Caches/Restart...
- Comando gradlew cleanBuildCache
- Comando gradlew.bat clean
- Archivo gradle.properties android.enableBuildCache=false

Pero ninguna de estas me ha resultado, sigo teniendo el permiso en el apk aunque no esté en el manifest y siguen creandose notificaciones aunque ya no exista código que las genere. Ayuda por favor :'(

Comment: Pueda que este en que usas algun componente externo que añade el permiso de CAMERA

Answer (score 0):

Con respecto a las preguntas que mencionas:

> Cuando comencé a crear mi aplicación tenía pensado usar la cámara por
>   lo cuál declare el permiso en el archivo Manifest.xml pero despues de
>   un tiempo decidí revocarlo borrándolo del Manifest.xml porque ya no lo
>   iba a utilizar. EL problema es que al crear el APK y ejecutarlo en el
>   dispositivo sigue apareciendo en permisos de la aplicación.
>
> sigo teniendo el permiso en el apk aunque no esté en el manifest y
>   siguen creandose notificaciones aunque ya no exista código que las
>   genere. Ayuda por favor

Si modificas los permisos o alguna propiedad dentro de tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` no es suficiente eliminar el caché de la aplicación. En este caso la aplicación debe ser eliminada y se debe volver a subir al dispositivo.

Comment: Ya la he eliminado muchas veces y la he vuelto a instalar y sigue apareciendo